# How to use a specific group of a DataFrameGroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I generate a sample dataframe and create the `grouped` variable with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)
nb_rows=50
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate((np.random.randint(1,4, (nb_rows, 2)), np.random.rand(nb_rows,1)),axis=1), index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=nb_rows, freq='D'), columns=['group1', 'group2', 'measure1'])
df['measure1'][df['measure1']>0.85] = np.nan
grouped = df.groupby(['group1','group2'])
```

which give this dataframe:

```
            group1 group2 measure1
2021-01-01  1.0 2.0 0.509624
2021-01-02  1.0 2.0 0.055715
2021-01-03  2.0 3.0 0.451159
2021-01-04  1.0 3.0 0.019988
2021-01-05  1.0 1.0 0.441711
2021-01-06  1.0 3.0 NaN
2021-01-07  2.0 3.0 0.359444
2021-01-08  3.0 1.0 0.480894
...
```

Now, I can perform a function on all groups, with something like that:

```
group_results = grouped['measure1'].apply(my_function_for_all)
```

where `my_function_for_all` is (just an example here, it could be anything):

```
def my_function_for_all(x):
  return np.sum(x**2)
```

If I have another function that I want to apply only to a particular group (e.g. for the group where `group1` = 1 and `group2` = 1), how would I do this? I can do something like that, but it doesn't return a Pandas series:

```
my_function_for_all(df[(df['group1'] == 1) & (df['group2'] == 1)]['measure1'])
```

Same when using the `get_group` function:

```
my_function_all(grouped.get_group((1,1))['measure1']))
```

I'm looking for a solution that would give me the same result as doing a specific groupby:

```
grouped_1 = df[(df['group1'] == 1) & (df['group2'] == 1)].groupby(['group1','group2'])
grouped_1['measure1'].apply(my_function_for_all)

group1  group2
1.0     1.0       1.412527
Name: measure1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grouped['measure1'].apply(my_function_for_all).loc[[(1.0,1.0)]]
```

will return pd.Series like at the end of the post.

```
grouped[['measure1']].apply(my_function_for_all).loc[[(1.0,1.0)],:]
```

will return pd.DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it doesn't provide the output that I want, where the output dataframe also contains the values for group1 and group2 (see the end of my post).

Comment: I edited the answer. Let me know if I misunderstood your question again.

Comment: That works, but it performs the apply operation on all groups. I'm trying to avoid that, hence why I want to filter for a specific group before applying the function.